# Selecting the parent element that is hiding its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I feel like this could have been asked before, but I can't seem to find it, so I'll ask myself.

I want to select the parent element that is the "cause" of its children being hidden. For example, a group of elements are essentially "hidden" but not because they have `display:none` but because some parent along the way has `display:none`.

If I only have a child element and I know that it is `hidden`, how might I easily find the parent that is causing it to be `hidden`.

I realize one solution is just to recursively loop through the parents such as...

```
function findHiddenParent(el){
  var $el = $(el);
  if($el.css('display') == 'none'){
    return $el;
  }
  return findHiddenParent($el.parent());
}
```

**Note I haven't tested the above code, its just for conceptualizing a solution**

But is there an easier way, perhaps through some *selector magic*?

Comment: You can use .parents() then filter that to the last element that is hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something similar to what you've got:

```
function findHiddenParents ( el ) {
    return $(el).parents().filter(function () {
        return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
    });
}
```

This'll return *all* ancestors that are hidden. If you only want the closest or the farthest, you can just return it with `.first()` or `.last()` respectively.

---

If you're not actually interested in *which* elements are hidden, but just want to reveal them all, then you can't get any simpler than this:

```
$(el).parents().show()
```

Comment: For a custom and dynamic solution this is probably the best. I know of *filter* but I do not know the particulars of its inner workings so I can't comment of how efficient it is.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.parents()` then filter that to the last element that is hidden.

```
$(child).parents(":hidden").last().show();
```

it will select the parent element highest in the hierarchy that has `display: none`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X9W2v/

*Note, `:hidden` will also select elements with a width/height of 0.*

Comment: An element is considered `:hidden` if its parent is hidden. Or if it has its height and width set to 0.

Comment: yes, .parents() will select them all, then you filter to the last one which should be the one that has display: none.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `:hidden` returns elements that do not have display:none. An element is considered :hidden if an ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

Comment: This is definitely the type of solution I was looking for, and for my particular situation this will work, but I must say that there are some situations in which it won't work such as if multiple parents have `display:none`

Comment: Yes, with multiple parents it will still only select the last one. Josephs answer would be better in that situation.

Comment: Although, wouldn't removing *.last()* and showing them all be harmless and would also solve the question? Because *showing* an element won't harm any element that has a "visible" display attribute

Comment: @andbeyond - The OP never asked to `show` them. They want to know what parent is causing it to be hidden. If they just want to reveal it, `$(el).parents().show()` would suffice.

Comment: @JosephSilber: I am the OP :) But yes I guess your right. In my particular solution I actually am looking to show them (just for a split second) but I figured that the way I originally asked it would be more wide-ranging and beneficial to others. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it in plain JavaScript. Somehow I feel it's cleaner than the jQuery solutions that involve loops or callbacks (Kevin B's one-liner looks great!). The cons are, it's longer, and it doesn't check computed styles:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a" style="display: none;">A
        <div id="b">B
            <div id="c">C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var currentNode = document.getElementById('c');
while(currentNode.parentNode && currentNode.style.display !== 'none') {
    currentNode = currentNode.parentNode;
}
alert(currentNode.id);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nc4h2/

Comment: +1 agree, when all you need is parentNode and style.display (and maybe a touch of offsetHeight), jQuery doesn't bring much value.